# How to Jump to Beginning of Chat in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to quickly jump to the beginning of a chat in Microsoft Teams? I have a conversation history that goes back months and is easily hundreds of pages long. Scrolling would take a long time.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of scrolling you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> repeatedly.

Once you've arrived at the first message you can click the menu of that message and select `Save this message`, this allows you to (sort of) easily go back to it via the `Saved` menu that appears when you click on your own profile photo in the top right.

Comment: Holding down CTRL+Home is even faster. Still very slow. If the message is old enough... say a couple of years, you can go back to it via Saved, but you won't be able to scroll up or down to see any other messages before or after it. ugh.

Answer (score 4):

If you recall a word in one of the early messages, you can try your luck **using the search** (trigger via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> while in a chat or just use the search bar at the top).

*Sometimes* **clicking one of the results** on the left (or *Go to message* if you used the global search) **lets you jump to the message directly** within the conversation history.

Also sometimes - *and for me it seems to be happening only in 1:1 chats and only for older messages* - clicking the message or "Go to message" will just show the message on its own with no context or history whatsoever...

Comment: Yes, I've also had that behaviour (only the single message shown for searches). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to search in the chat for some less common words. In my case "therefore" showed up some old messages a couple of months before the start. From there I clicked the message and repeatedly pushed home to go back to the start.